# How kernel know the difference between "int 0x80" and "int x"

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

int 0x80 is a system call, it's also 128 in hexa.
why kernel use int 0x80 as interrupt and when i declare int x he knows it's just an integer named x and vice versa ?

Comment: Are you confused about the difference between C (in which `int x;` declares an integer variable named `x`, and `int <number>` is a syntax error) and x86 assembly language (in which `int <number>` generates machine code for the INTerrupt instruction, and `int x;` is a syntax error)?  Otherwise I do not understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Let me try and be abit more clear.
How the compiler (in c) know the difference between the definision of a variable x to be integer like in a code "int x" and the system_call interrupt "int 0x80" ?

Answer (score 7):

You appear to be confused about the difference between C and assembly language.  Both are programming languages, (nowadays) both accept the `0xNNNN` notation for writing numbers in hexadecimal, and there's usually some way to embed tiny snippets of assembly language in a C program, but they are *different languages*.  The keyword `int` means something completely different in C than it does in (x86) assembly language.

To a C compiler, `int` *always* and *only* means to declare something involving an integer, and there is no situation where you can immediately follow `int` with a numeric literal. `int 0x80` (or `int 128`, or `int 23`, or anything else of the sort) is always a syntax error in C.

To an x86 assembler, `int` *always* and *only* means to generate machine code for the INTerrupt instruction, and a valid operand for that instruction (an "imm8", i.e. a number in the range 0–255) must be the next thing on the line. `int x;` is a syntax error in x86 assembly language, unless `x` has been defined as a constant in the appropriate range using the assembler's macro facilities.

Obvious follow-up question: If a C compiler doesn't recognize `int` as the INTerrupt instruction, how does a C program (compiled for x86) make system calls?  There are four complementary answers to this question:

1. Most of the time, in a C program, you do not make system calls directly.  Instead, you call functions in the C library that do it for you.  When processing your program, as far as the C compiler knows, `open` (for instance) is no different than any other external function.  So it doesn't *need* to generate an `int` instruction.  It just does `call open`.
2. But the C library is just more C that someone else wrote for you, isn't it?  Yet, if you disassemble the implementation of `open`, you will indeed see an `int` instruction (or maybe `syscall` or `sysenter` instead).  How did the people who wrote the C library do that?  *They wrote that function in assembly language, not in C.*  Or they used that technique for embedding snippets of assembly language in a C program, which brings us to ...
3. How does *that* work?  Doesn't that mean the C compiler *does* need to understand `int` as an assembly mnemonic sometimes?  Not necessarily.  Let's look at the GCC syntax for inserting assembly—this could be an implementation of `open` for x86/32/Linux:

   ```
    int open(const char *path, int flags, mode_t mode)
    {
        int ret;
        asm ("int 0x80" 
             : "=a" (ret) 
             : "0" (SYS_open), "d" (path), "c" (flags), "D" (mode));
        if (ret >= 0) return ret;
        return __set_errno(ret);
     }
   ```

   You don't need to understand the bulk of that: the important thing for purpose of this question is, yes, it says `int 0x80`, but it says it *inside a string literal*.  The compiler will copy the contents of that string literal, verbatim, into the generated assembly-language file that it will then feed to the assembler.  It doesn't need to know what it means.  That's the assembler's job.
4. More generally, there are lots of words that mean one thing in C and a completely different thing in assembly language.  A C compiler *produces* assembly language, so it has to "know" both of the meanings of those words, right?  It does, but it does not confuse them, because they are always used in separate contexts.  "add" being an assembly mnemonic that the C compiler knows how to use, does not mean that there is any problem with naming a variable "add" in a C program, even if the "add" instruction gets used in that program.