# Why does glibc library use assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, glibc

[Glibc and System Call Layer Documentation](https://sys.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc/01_introduction.html) explains how glibc does system calls.

In one of the examples, the code is examined and it is shown, that the last instruction glibc does to **actually** do a system call (meaning the interrupt to the cpu), is written in assembly.

So why is part of glibc in assembly? Is there some sort of advantage by writing that small part in assembly?

Also, the shared libraries during runtime are already compiled to machine code correct?

So why would there be any advantage using two different languages before compilation?

Comment: The compiler doesn't support generating the machine code for the interrupt to the CPU part.

Comment: If it weren't written in assembly, what C statement would be used?

Comment: Why is it in any way surprising for parts of the C standard library to be implemented in a lower-level language?  All sorts of high-level languages are typically implemented in lower-level ones. Python, Java, Ruby, Perl, and many others are all in this category.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is super simple - since C doesn't cover system calls (because it doesn't cover any physical hardware in general, and prefers to express itself in terms of abstract machine), there is no C construct `glibc` can use to perform system call.

One could argue that compiler could provide a sort of intrinsic to do that, but since in Linux glibc is actually part of the compiler suit of tools (in contains CRT as well) there is really no need for it, glibc can do the job.

Also, last, but not the least, in modern CPUs syscall is usually not an interrupt. Instead, it's a specific instruction (`syscall` in x86_64).

Comment: Did you mean "glibc can't use any C construct" where you have "glibc can use ..." ?

Comment: @zwol, yeah, this was superunclear, thanks for pointing it out. I rephrased it, hope it is better now.

Comment: @SergeyA... I see and understand what you mean by glibc not wanting to cover any hardware specifically.... but, let's just say for the sake of learning, that you wanted to write a C function for glibc for x86 platform system calls, could you do it? So instead of having the assembly in glibc, you could have another C function that would do the same. I know it would be pretty pointless and all, but I am just curious if it's even possible. Thank you.

Comment: @hescobar1013 You could write a bunch of functions like the one in [list item 3 of this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36460029/388520), and in fact that is exactly what glibc does (buried under a mountain of macros, for historical reasons) -- but there's an inline assembly operation in the body of the function, and that is unavoidable.

Comment: @zwol....Thank you for that link, that answer was very interesting as well...so I get it, in the context of glibc and gcc, assembly is needed for multiple reasons, one of them being that glibc doesn't want to concern itself with hardware level "stuff" and be agnostic.... but for the sake of learning, OUTSIDE of glibc and gcc, would it be possible to write a C library and a C compiler for x86 platform, that would be able to forego using assembly? So you could make a compiler that would understand to turn "int 0x80" or something similar, to machine code to execute a system call right? Thank you.

Comment: There _is_ a `syscall` _function_ that apps can use [usually the preferred way to bypass `glibc` for syscalls] but `glibc` doesn't use it internally. An x86 syscall, can come from [at least] three different machine instructions [depending on OS's implementation and what the given arch/model supports]: `int 0x80`, `syscall`, or `sysenter`. So, it's better to let the library decide. Also, when a syscall returns, IIRC, the x86 `carry` hardware flag is set/cleared depending upon error, so each lib fnc that does a syscall needs to handle this to set `errno` properly [and this is best done in asm]

Comment: @hescobar No, what both answers are trying to tell you is that you really can't.  Also I do not understand what you mean by "glibc doesn't want to concern itself with hardware level stuff"; in fact, it _does_ concern itself with all kinds of hardware level stuff.

Comment: @CraigEstey You're not really bypassing glibc when you use `syscall`; that, too, is a function exported from `libc.so`.

Comment: @zwol Yes. I meant, for example, one could bypass the `read` function using `syscall(SYS_read,...)`. This is necessary for something like `gettid` which has no glibc wrapper function.

Answer (score 6):

I want to address this piece of your question:

> Also, the shared libraries during runtime are already compiled to machine code correct?
>   So why would there be any advantage using two different languages before compilation?

SergeyA correctly points out that there *isn't* any C construct (even with all of GCC's extensions) that will cause the compiler to emit a `syscall` instruction.  That's not the only thing that the C library is supposed to do that simply can't be written purely in C: the implementations of `setjmp` and `longjmp`, `makecontext` and `setcontext`, the "entry point" code that calls `main`, the "trampoline" that you return to when you return from a signal handler, and several other low-level bits all require a little bit of hand-written assembly.  (Exercise: what do they all have in common?)

But there's another reason to mix assembly language into a program mostly written in C.  [This is one of the several implementations of `memcpy` for x86-64 in glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S;hb=HEAD).  It is 3100 lines of hand-written assembly language and preprocessor macros.  What it does could be expressed in four lines of C.  Why would anyone go to that much trouble?  *Speed.*  Compilers are always getting closer, but they haven't yet quite managed to beat the human brain when it comes to squeezing every last possible cycle out of a critical innermost loop.  (It is worth mentioning that in early 2018 the glibc devs spent a bunch of time replacing hand-written assembly implementations of `math.h` functions with C, because the compilers *have* caught up on those, and C is ever so much more maintainable.)

And yet a third answer, which isn't particularly relevant to glibc but comes up a bunch elsewhere, is that maybe you have two different languages in your program because each of them is better at part of your problem.  The statistical language R is mostly implemented in C, but a bunch of its mathematical primitives are (or were, I haven't checked in a while) written in FORTRAN, because FORTRAN is still the language that numerical computation wizards think in.  Both C and FORTRAN get compiled to machine code, and in principle you *could* rewrite all the FORTRAN in C, but nobody wants to.

Comment: "FORTRAN is still the language that numerical computation wizards think in" -- it's not just a matter of which language they think in -- lack of pointer aliasing in FORTRAN allows much more aggressive optimizations, often resulting in faster machine code.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I _think_ that in principle you can get the same optimization level in C with careful use of `restrict`, but it's a good point anyway: learning how to "think" in C would involve learning all the things like that, that you have to do in C but not in FORTRAN, so the switching costs are even higher than they appear at first glance.