# Is it possible to write fopen(), fscanf() or fprintf() functions using only C?

Tags: c

I have no issues with the library functions. I know that they work well. I am interested in their implementation. My question is: Can I write working versions of these functions for Windows x64 using only C?

Comment: You may be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884412/why-does-glibc-library-use-assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the stnadard library functions are written in C, and `fopen`, `fread` etc. are no exception. You can write a wrapper around `open`, `read`, `write` etc. which are usually lower level functions.

If those are not available, you can also do the same, calling the respective OS functions and wrapping them with your own implementation, you just have to make sure that they are complying to the standard.

Just as an example you can find a source for `fopen` [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/ics-mr0/libc/stdio/fopen.c).